# How to make a bitmap to fit to the button whenever the button is stretched?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am having button and on which I am trying to load a bitmap and able to load the bitmap on the button.But when I run my exe on an japanese win7 enterprise Operating system then my button's are a bit stretched and the bitmap did not get stretched and was not fit to the button area.
Can anyone please let me know how can we make the bitmap to get strecthed and fit to the button whenever the button is stretched.

Comment: Can you show the code of how you place the bitmap on your button?

Answer (score 0):

You have to derive you own owner draw button class. You need to overwrite OnDrawItem and use StretchBlt to draw the bitmap into the buttons client area.

Just use the code you find in the MFC in CBitmapButton...

Comment: If we do so,will the bitmap get's stretched when the button size is increased?

Comment: When the button receives the WM_SIZE message the client area is invalidated and the button is redrawn. This is the default. If you have problems, simply add a WM_SIZE handler and call Invalidate...

Answer (score 0):

You may be asking the wrong question. You could get the size of the bitmap and then change the button size (with MoveWindow) to match the bitmap.